# How to implement superuser in RBAC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, rbac, dbt

Do you have any clue what is the best approach to implement **RBAC** in **AWS**.
I have 2 main problems:

1. Since we have 3 environments, **dev**, **test**, **prod** - is it better to create unique roles per environment or use common roles rules for all environments and add exceptions per environment?
2. Since we use **DBT** some users needs to be ***superusers*** in **Redshift**. However I don't know how to create superuser role. And for now we assign superuser as that in exception file:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: user
      author: author
      runOnChange: xxxx
      comment: xxxxx
      changes:
        - sql:
            splitStatements: false
            sql: >
              ALTER USER username CREATEUSER;
```

Do you know any way to do so ?

I read thru AWS documentation [rbac aws](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/red-ug/Clusters.RBAC.html).